# How to find Spring dependencies after project is initialized?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to Spring world. I am following Spring Microservices in Action, where they recommend to use Spring Intializr to get Spring dependencies. However, post that whenever we need to add new dependencies, maven dependencies are provided in book. What would professionals do in such situation? How will new dependencies be found and added to the `pom.xml`?

Comment: If you use maven to manage dependency, you can try with cmd `mvn dependency:tree` to show the dependency tree of your project. Or use dependency plugin of your idea to manage it.

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your comment. I wish to know about adding new dependencies not check the existing once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them in public repositories like https://mvnrepository.com or search for *Maven Central* alternatives.

Also, you can find your needed dependency on that third-party library's official website, for example, if you want to add *Lombok* dependency to your project simply find it in https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven

One the other way is [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) ad you said. Just find and add the dependency inside this website and then click on the **Explore** link at the bottom of the main page:

[image]

And take a look at the `pom.xml` file. You can see the dependency:

[image]

There are absolutely multiple other ways like finding and adding the dependency in your **IDE** (IntelliJ, Eclipse ...) and ...